# Tkinter move images one after another

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I trying to move two images one after another but both images start moving at the same time. Basically, what I want is to wait until Image1 arrive at destination and then Image2 starts moving. Here is my code

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk
from PIL import Image
import time

class gui(tk.Frame):

def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
    self.canvas =  tk.Canvas(parent, bg="blue", highlightthickness=0)
    self.canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    self.img = tk.PhotoImage(file="Club14.gif")
    self.card1 = self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=self.img, anchor="nw")
    self.card2= self.canvas.create_image(800, 800, image=self.img, anchor="nw")
    self.move_object(self.canvas, self.card1, [400, 410], 8)
    self.move_object(self.canvas, self.card2, [400, 440], 8)



def move_object(self, canvas, object_id, destination, speed=50):
    dest_x, dest_y = destination
    coords = self.canvas.coords(object_id)
    current_x = coords[0]
    current_y = coords[1]

    new_x, new_y = current_x, current_y
    delta_x = delta_y = 0
    if current_x < dest_x:
        delta_x = 1
    elif current_x > dest_x:
        delta_x = -1

    if current_y < dest_y:
        delta_y = 1
    elif current_y > dest_y:
        delta_y = -1

    if (delta_x, delta_y) != (0, 0):
        canvas.move(object_id, delta_x, delta_y)

    if (new_x, new_y) != (dest_x, dest_y):
        canvas.after(speed, self.move_object, canvas, object_id, destination, speed)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    w, h = root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()
    root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (w, h))
    gui(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't see the problem. If you want to wait to start the second item from moving  until later, don't call `self.move_object` a second time until you're ready for it to start moving.

Answer (score 0):

To move items of your canvas **sequentially**, you could put them in a list and define a method such as `run_move_sequence()` below, that starts moving each item only after the previous one has reached its destination:

[image: animated GIF]

```
import tkinter as tk

class gui(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.canvas =  tk.Canvas(parent, width=200, height=200)
        self.canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        self.objects = [self.canvas.create_oval(10, 10, 30, 30, fill="blue"),
                        self.canvas.create_rectangle(170, 170, 190, 190, fill="yellow") ]
        self.destinations = [ [90, 75], [90, 100] ]
        self.speed = 20
        self.start_move_sequence()

    def start_move_sequence(self):
        self.moveDone = False
        self.count = 0
        self.run_move_sequence()

    def run_move_sequence(self):
        if self.moveDone == False:
            self.move_object(self.objects[self.count], self.destinations[self.count])
            self.canvas.after(self.speed, self.run_move_sequence)
        else:
            # Start run_move_sequence on the next object
            self.count += 1
            if self.count < len(self.objects):
                self.moveDone = False
                self.run_move_sequence()

    def move_object(self, object_id, destination):
        dest_x, dest_y = destination
        coords = self.canvas.coords(object_id)
        current_x, current_y = coords[0], coords[1]

        new_x, new_y = current_x, current_y
        delta_x = delta_y = 0
        if current_x < dest_x:
            delta_x = 1
        elif current_x > dest_x:
            delta_x = -1

        if current_y < dest_y:
            delta_y = 1
        elif current_y > dest_y:
            delta_y = -1

        if (delta_x, delta_y) != (0, 0):
            self.canvas.move(object_id, delta_x, delta_y)

        if (new_x, new_y) == (dest_x, dest_y):
            self.moveDone = True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    gui(root)
    root.mainloop()
```